# Are two identical sequential reads in a Postgres transaction guaranteed return the same records?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, race-condition

I was wondering if transactions in Postgres freeze the state of a table, similar to the way a  point-in-time does in Elasticsearch.

If have a query with a `where` clause, and I inside a transaction I run it, first as a `count(*)`, then with a `select`, and finally, with an `update`, do I need to be worried about a different process inserting a record into the db and throwing off the results?

Comment: Rather then repeating the docs I suggest reading [Transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/transaction-iso.html). And for more in depth [Concurrency Control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/mvcc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default transaction isolation level `READ COMMITTED`, each statement in a transaction sees a different state (*snapshot*) of the database.

If you want all statements in a transaction to see the same snapshot, you will have to use the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level. However, there is the possibility that concurrent data manipulations cause the `UPDATE` to fail with a serialization error, forcing you to repeat the transaction.